# How do you rename the admin catalog Position label?

Tags: magento2

How do you rename the admin catalog Position label?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product` class is responsible for generating this product's grid. We can rewrite the `_prepareColumns` method in this class to make changes in the grid. Please follow the example below:

> app/code/MilanDev/CustomBlock/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" type="MilanDev\CustomBlock\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/MilanDev/CustomBlock/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tab/Product.php

```
<?php
namespace MilanDev\CustomBlock\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Your Text'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
            ]
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```